# displaying time when page is refreshed

Tags: html, xml, xslt

In my xslt file, is it possible to display the time (with the help of a label) whenever the browser detects a page refresh? How is it done?

Answer (score 0):

You can emit javascript that writes out the local time.

Comment: can u help me with the code? I wish to use that code in my xslt file directly pls.